# Create Relationship between child nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I want to create a new relationship between nodes of the same label based on their relationship to the same parent node. The attached picture is an example:

[image: Nodes overview]

Only (Person)/Authors that worked on the **same** Article should have a relationship [WORKED_WITH] to another. Is there an elegant way, to do this using cypher or maybe apoc? So far the only solution I came up with is by creating a RESULT of each article name with a list (collect) of the authors. Which then would have to be used (py2neo) to create the relationship.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the purpose of a `Contributio` node, and what is the reason the `CONTRIUTIO_HAS_AUTHOR` relationships are not directly connected to an `Article` node instead? Also, to your main question: is there a real need to add `WORKED_WITH` relationships (which adds redundant data) to your data model?

Comment: Hi, the idea behind the Contributio is that different Contributio and therefore Authors could be attached to the same Article. The reason for the WORKED_WITH Realtionship is to use GDS algorithms like centrality or community detection on the authors. I found the following code:

https://community.neo4j.com/t/iterating-through-an-array-of-ids-to-create-relationships-between-them/19017/3

Which works,but takes a lot of time.

Comment: Do you mean that there can be multiple "contributions" to the same article, and each contribution can have multiple authors?

Comment: A pair of `Author`s can work together on more than one `Article`, so should every `WORKED_WITH` relationship specify some sort of unique `Article` identifier?